# How to chose optimal initial pheromone value for a ant colony algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis

I am trying to develop an ant colony optimization algorithm that will minimize the electricity load shedding on a given graph. The graph has some supply vertices  and some demand vertices. Supply vertices have the electricity to supply to the other demand vertices. It assume that the supply vertices fulfil its demand then supply to the other demand vertices.

In my method an artificial ant starts from a supply vertex with the electricity that the vertex generated. It will traverse the graph and give the electricity to the demand vertex until the electricity empty that the ant carried. This same ant placed in every supply vertices and distribute the electricity to the demand vertices. Note that if the ant reach in ant supply vertex then the ant do nothing and simply select the next vertex. If there are 10 ants then that 10 ants will distribute the electricity to the graph in 10 way. Note that the every ant will place to the source vertex every time randomly, so that it will ensure that there will no predetermined sequence. After get the result from that 10 ants separately we calculate the which ant has the graph that has minimum load shedding. Then 
the pheromone trail will be updated according to path that the ant made.

This is the simple ant colony system that I implemented. To select the next vertex from $i$ to $j$, I used this method:

$$p_{ij}^k = \frac{[\tau_{ij}]^\alpha[\eta_{ij}]^\beta}{\sum_{\ell\in\mathcal{N}_i^k}[\tau_{i\ell}]^\alpha[\eta_{i\ell}]^\beta},\quad\text{if }j\in\mathcal{N}_i^k\,,$$

where the $\eta$ will represent the heuristic value of the next vertex. In my algorithm that is the load shedding value of the next vertex. And the $\tau$ is the pheromone value of the edge between $i$ to $j$. For the reference I am using [this](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/ant-colony-optimization) book.

The problem is I am not sure how to chose the initial pheromone value. Because the load shedding value is random and and range from 0 to infinity. Therefore this value dominate to chose the next vertex and it act like a greed algorithm. But if the pheromone value will taken carefully then the fluctuation of probability to chose next vertex vary.
Every ant makes the different result only that the ant place in source vertices random sequence.
So My question , what is the method or observation to chose the pheromone value for the initial state.

This is github repository of the code for this algorithm -
`https://github.com/muztaba/SmartGridOptimization`
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science Stack Exchange. Please read
http://cs.stackexchange.com/tour, if you have not yet done so. When
posting a question, make sure to give enough context, and show how you
tried to answer it on your own, so as to be very precise regarding
your problem. This helps better answers and future readers.

Comment: What research have you done, and what have you found so far?  What resources have you looked at, to see how ant colony optimization is to be done?  Did any of them say anything about initialization, and if so, what did they say?  What was unsatisfactory about what you found?  Doing research before asking helps you frame a more specific question, helps others give you better answers, and helps others who might have a similar question and might come across your post.  This might involve looking at textbooks, spending some time at the library, or reading research papers.

Comment: @D.W. Thank you for your valuable suggestion. I rewrote the thread. Please take look.

Comment: @babou Thank you for your valuable suggestion. I rewrote the thread. Please take look.